# Want to center a marketing div and put a box around it - Using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I am trying to center marketing div and put a box around it. I would like to keep the marketing div small and in the center.

The .box is just a simple box with a border.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="row box">
            <div class="marketing">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
             </div>

             <div class="col-lg-3">
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quidam debitis honestatis ut eam. Dicant perpetua pro an, id mei iusto ridens. Cibo salutatus has ex..</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                    <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quidam debitis honestatis ut eam.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

It's extending the box too far to the right and I can't figure out why it's not even on both sides.

Link[1](http://jsfiddle.net/rUFkT/)

Comment: By far to right ...do you mean left :P..This is what I see: http://jsfiddle.net/rUFkT/

Comment: If you'll create a fiddle link with css..chances are people will respond quickly and you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your columns don't quite add up. Instead, you can nest another row of 12 columns inside of an existing column. Try:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
            <div class="row box">
                <div class="marketing">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quidam debitis honestatis ut eam. Dicant perpetua pro an, id mei iusto ridens. Cibo salutatus has ex..</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="placeholder" class="img-rounded">
                        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                        <p class="marketing-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quidam debitis honestatis ut eam.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rUFkT/) (columns are only set for large so make sure the window is large enough)